# perplexing check box behavior

Tags: php, laravel, methods

I have a edit form with some checkboxes that I am trying to make checked when the associated many to many relationship is established.

Distributors belong to many beers
Beers belong to many distributors

in my controller I have:

```
        $breweries = Brewery::lists('name', 'id');
        $all_dist = Distributor::all();
        $beer = Beer::find($id);
        $distributions = [];
        foreach ($beer->distributors as $distributor)
            {
                $distributions[$distributor->id] = BeerDistribution::where('beer_id', '=', $beer->id)
                ->where('distributor_id', '=', $distributor->id)->first()->price;
            }

        return View::make('beers.edit', ['beer' => $beer, 'distributors' => $all_dist, 'distributions' => $distributions, 'breweries' => $breweries, 'styles' => $styles]);
```

and I in my edit form I have:

```
        {{ Form::model($beer, ['route' => ['beers.update', $beer->id], 'method' => 'PATCH']) }}
            @foreach ($distributors as $distributor)
                <?php $carried = in_array($distributor->id, array_keys($distributions)) ? true : false ?>
                {{ Form::checkbox('distributors[]', $distributor->id, $carried); }}
                {{ Form::label($distributor->name) }}
                {{ Form::label('price' . $distributor->id, 'Retail:') }}
                <?php $price = $carried ? $distributions[$distributor->id] : null ?>
                {{ Form::text('price' . $distributor->id, $price ) }}
            @endforeach
            {{ Form::submit('Save') }}
        {{ Form::close() }}
```

Basically I am passing an associated array of each distributor_id => price. This array also tells me which distributors the beer already belongs to so that I can mark those checked off in my edit form.

Here's where things get wonky. When I load this form, all the checkboxes will be checked no matter what. If I change my controller loop to this:

`foreach ($beer->distributors()->lists('distributor_id') as $distributor_id)`

Then I can do create my array.

Why does calling `$beer->distributors` in the controller would result in all the checkboxes being checked?

Comment: With the original foreach, if you var_dump your `$distributions` array after the foreach, does it look like you'd expect?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the last argument : `$carried`

```
{{ Form::checkbox('distributors[]', $distributor->id, [ "checked" => $carried ]); }}
```

Pass the last parameter as array, and tell it exactly which attribute to modify and the attribute value.

Comment: The OPs parameter placement is correct.  The third parameter to the `Form::checkbox()` method is a boolean to determine if the checkbox should be checked. The options array is the fourth parameter.

Comment: Yes, and to further back that up, I could remove `$carried` and all the checkboxes would still show up checked. Even if I don't pass in the variables I instantiate in my controller, the checkboxes would still be checked.

Comment: @hodale try to pass only false instead of $carried variable

Comment: It might be worthwhile to see if I can override the truthiness being applied, but this wouldn't help explain the problem to begin with.